# Can I use Allegro in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, allegro

I'm trying to make simple games, because I want to teach design patterns and lot of things. 
But I and my students are using VS2017 and I'd seen that allegro supports until VS2012... so we'll have problems of compability or something like that? If these is the case, your can recommend me another option to use instead of allegro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes by doing the following:

Right click on your project name, and select Manage NuGet Packages.
Go to the Browse tab and search for Allegro in the search bar. You should see the main Allegro 5 package there.
Press the Install button on the right.

you can see this :
https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2015_and_Nuget_Allegro_5
https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2017/11/03/Allegro-Tutorial-Series-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx

[image]